Deduplicate records that came within 31 days
I need query in BigQuery to select first records with in 31 days cycle and all the records with in 31 days will be eliminated.
More details: if a customer has more than one visits in a 31-day period, include only the first eligible visit. For example, if a customer has an visit on January 1, include the January 1 visit and do not include other visits that occur on or between January 2 and January 31; then, if applicable, include the next eligible visit that occurs on or after February 1. Identify visits chronologically, including only one per 31-day period.
CTE for sample data:
WITH customer_visit AS 
(
    SELECT '554' AS CUS_ID, '2023-12-31' AS visit_date UNION ALL
    SELECT '555' AS CUS_ID, '2023-12-31' AS visit_date UNION ALL
    SELECT '555' AS CUS_ID, '2024-01-16' AS visit_date UNION ALL
    SELECT '555' AS CUS_ID, '2024-01-30' AS visit_date UNION ALL
    SELECT '555' AS CUS_ID, '2024-02-05' AS visit_date UNION ALL
    SELECT '555' AS CUS_ID, '2024-02-10' AS visit_date UNION ALL
    SELECT '555' AS CUS_ID, '2024-02-15' AS visit_date UNION ALL
    SELECT '555' AS CUS_ID, '2024-02-29' AS visit_date UNION ALL
    SELECT '555' AS CUS_ID, '2024-03-06' AS visit_date
)

Expected output:
CUS_ID   visit_date
-------------------
  554    2023-12-31
  555    2023-12-31
  555    2024-02-05
  555    2024-03-06

I tried different logic with lag and row functions but still not able to get required results. Might someone be able to help make this work and this will help other people going forward as well?

One way to do it is to generate as many rows as there are posssible perids of 31 days. The rows will be used for calculation of start and end date of periods that last 31 day each. The first period depend on customer id and his very first visit date. All following period's start dates per customer are the first visiting date after the end of previous period.
Since I don't use Bigquery - here is the code (tested with Oracle and with Postgres) that you might need to adjust to your actual context:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
CREATE TABLE  
  customer_visit (CUS_ID Int, VISIT_DATE Date);
Insert Into customer_visit (CUS_ID, VISIT_DATE) 
VALUES
  ( '554', '2023-12-31' ), 
  ( '555', '2023-12-31' ), 
  ( '555', '2024-01-16' ), 
  ( '555', '2024-01-30' ), 
  ( '555', '2024-02-05' ), 
  ( '555', '2024-02-10' ), 
  ( '555', '2024-02-15' ), 
  ( '555', '2024-02-29' ), 
  ( '555', '2024-03-06' ); 

... generating periods with a recursive cte - you can use any other row generator to do it ( like Oracle's LEVEL ... CONNECT BY )
WITH
  Recursive dates (PASS, CUS_ID,  VISIT_DATE) AS 
      ( Select 0, CUS_ID,  VISIT_DATE
        From   customer_visit
       UNION ALL
        Select PASS + 1, CUS_ID, VISIT_DATE
        From     dates 
        Where    PASS < Ceil( (Select Max(VISIT_DATE) - Min(VISIT_DATE) From customer_visit) / 31 )  -- Ceil() gets first bigger Integer
      )

... Join your data to the cte, calculate start-end dates for periods per customer, get row numbers per customer and period and select just the first row of each group...
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT    CUS_ID, VISIT_DATE
FROM    ( Select    cv.CUS_ID, cv.VISIT_DATE, d.CUS_START_DATE, d.CUS_END_DATE,  
                    Row_Number() Over(Partition By cv.CUS_ID, d.CUS_START_DATE, d.CUS_END_DATE Order By cv.VISIT_DATE) as RN
          From      customer_visit cv
          Left Join ( Select   PASS, CUS_ID, 
                               Min(VISIT_DATE + (PASS * 31)) as CUS_START_DATE, 
                               Min(VISIT_DATE + ( ((PASS + 1) * 31)) - 1 ) as CUS_END_DATE
                      From     dates
                      Group By PASS, CUS_ID
                    ) d ON( d.CUS_ID = cv.CUS_ID And
                            cv.VISIT_DATE Between d.CUS_START_DATE And CUS_END_DATE )
        )
WHERE     RN = 1
ORDER BY  CUS_ID, VISIT_DATE

/*    R e s u l t : 
cus_id  visit_date
------  ----------
   554  2023-12-31
   555  2023-12-31
   555  2024-02-05
   555  2024-03-06      */

See the Postgres fiddle here.
See the Oracle fiddle here.
